# MatLab memory allocation when max size is unknown

Tags: matlab, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am trying to speed up a script that I have written in Matlab that dynamically allocates memory to a matrix (basicallly reads a line of data from a file and writes it into a matrix, then reads another line and allocates more memory for a larger matrix to store the next line).  The reason I did this instead of preallocating memory using zeroes() or something was that I don't know the exact size the matrix needs to be to hold all of the data.  I also don't know the maximum size of the matrix, so I can't just preallocate a max size and then get rid of memory that I didn't use.  This was fine for small amounts of data, but now I need to scale my script up to read many millions of data points and this implementation of dynamic allocation is just much too slow.

So here is my attempt to speed up the script:  I tried to allocate memory in large blocks using the zeroes function, then once the block is filled I allocate another large block.  Here is some sample code:

```
data = [];   
count = 0;

for ii = 1:num_filelines    
   if mod(count, 1000) == 0  
       data = [data; zeroes(1000)];  %after 1000 lines are read, allocate another 1000 line
   end  
   data(ii, :) = line_read(file);  %line_read reads a line of data from 'file'
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, when I run it I get an error saying "Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

So here is my question: Is this method of allocating memory in large blocks actually any faster than incremental dynamic allocation, and also why does the above code not run?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: when you do zeros(1000) you are allocating a 1000x1000 matrix of zeros. This may be why your code is not running. As for allocation speed, it is always good to preallocate in matlab, but instead of using arrays, when reading in lines, use cells to store the data. This way you do not have so much of a problem. Either that, or use a sparse matrix.

Comment: This will be somewhat dependent on the version of Matlab you use. Recent versions have been shown to be very fast at dynamic memory allocation. [Read more](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I recommend doing, if you know the number of lines and can just guess a large enough number of acceptable columns, use a `sparse matrix`.

```
% create a sparse matrix
mat = sparse(numRows,numCols)
```

A sparse matrix will not store all of the zero elements, it only stores pointers to indices that are non-zero. This can help save a lot of space. They are used and accessed the same as any other matrix. That is only if you really need it in a matrix format from the beginning.

If not, you can just do everything as a `cell`. Preallocate a `cell array` with as many elements as lines in your file.

```
data = cell(1,numLines);
% get matrix from line
for i = 1:numLines
    % get matrix from line
    data{i} = lineData;
end
data = cell2mat(data);
```

This method will put everything into a cell array, which can store "*dynamically*" and then be converted to a regular matrix.

**Addition**

If you are doing the sparse matrix method, to trim up your matrix once you are done, because your matrix will likely be larger than necessary, you can trim this down easily, and then cast it to a regular matrix.

```
[val,~] = max(sum(mat ~= 0,2));
mat(:,val:size(mat,2)) = [];
mat = full(mat); % use this only if you really need the full matrix
```

This will remove any unnecessary columns and then cast it to a full matrix that includes the 0 elements. I would not recommend casting it to a full matrix, as this requires a ton more space, but if you truly need it, use it.

**UPDATE**

To get the number of lines in a file easily, use MATLAB's perl interpretter

create a file called `countlines.pl` and paste in the two lines below

```
while (<>) {};
print $.,"\n";
```

Then you can run this script on your file as follows

```
numLines = str2double(perl('countlines.pl','data.csv'));
```

Problem solved.

From MATLAB forum thread [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235126)

remember it is always best to preallocate everything before hand, because technically when doing shai's method you are reallocating large amounts a lot, especially if it is a large file.

Comment: you might want to reserve space for the non-zeros in the sparse matrix, by "guessin"/estimating the number of non-zeros

Comment: @Shai I am not sure what you mean, the sparse matrix will handle allocation and whatever else for you.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I actually don't know how many lines I need.  Shai's fix to the code that I posted solves the issue that I had, and drastically speeds up my script.  Thanks for the suggestion of using sparse() and pointers though, I didn't think of that.  Now that my issue is solved I am curious, does my method scale linearly with the number of lines of data, or is it just much better than adding new rows dynamically? I guess I don't understand why allocating memory in blocks is more efficient

Comment: I posted a method to get the number of lines in the file, it is quick and easy. and will work for large numbers as well

Comment: I didn't know Matlab had a perl interpreter, I guess that method would scale better with the number of lines of data I need to read than my method.  I actually don't really understand why my method is any faster than just reallocating every step (it certainly is though).

Comment: @MZimmerman6 see the second use example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) the argument `nzmax`.

Comment: @Shai yes you could do that. It will likely speed stuff up, but that will become apparent once data is being loaded. You do not necessarily want to overload memory though that may not be needed, especially if you are running a system with little RAM.

Comment: Even if you don't know the number of lines it's much faster to use cell and to iterate through all lines in the end, writing them into an matrix (of correct size) than using a sparse matrix in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your error, simply use this syntax when allocating

```
data = [data; zeroes(1000, size(data,2))];
```

You might want to read the first line outside the loop so you'll know the number of columns and make the first allocation for `data`.

Comment: Yes that was error, not entering the correct number of columns for the zeroes matrix, oops.  I happen to know how many columns I need while the number of lines is unkown, but reading the first line separately is also an excellent idea to make the script more generalized, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your code as written I would substitute your initialization of data, `data = []` to

```
data = zeros(1,1000);
```

Keep in mind though the warning from @MZimmerman6: `zeros(1000)` generates a 1000 x 1000 array. You may want to change all of your `zeros` statements to `zeros( ... ,Nc)`, where Nc = length of line in characters.